# No "New" button and View:Grid in TFS. Why ? So how i can export test cases to TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

i have to export a lot of Test Cases ( contains Steps ) to TFS

but in my TFS does not appear the "New"  button and View:Grid option . Why ? How i can to achieve it ?

[my tfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XzsO.png)

[tfs that i wont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GJEL.png)

or how i can to export Test Cases and Stept into TFS ? Maybe  i need to install something ?

thanks you for help !

PS : [my tfs after creating Test suites and test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJmZa.png)

I use Visual Studio 2017 and TFS 2017 ( and TFS 2018 in another comp )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you are lacking test suites. We organize our test cases by **adding test cases to test suites**.

1. If you haven't already, [create a test plan and requirement-based
   test suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/create-a-test-plan?view=vsts) first.
2. Select a requirement-based test suite, and then create a test case
   for that suite.

[image]

To quickly add multiple test cases at the same time,use the grid view when you add test cases to the test suite.

[image]

More details please refer the official tutorial in MSDN: **[Create manual test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/create-test-cases?view=vsts)**

According to your update screenshot, you are lacking of the usage of **[Test Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web#overview)** extension. Perhaps your trial(30 days) is out of date. You have to buy the extension or use some Visual Studio subscriptions which included the extension.

Comment: thanks you for your answer ! 
i created test cases ,  but have no "New" button and "view:grid" option still...
my version of TFS - 2017  maybe that a problem ?

Comment: HI, @AnnaC25 Please see my update answer, according to your update screenshot, you are lacking of the usage of [Test Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web#overview) extension. Perhaps your trail(30 days) is out of date. You have to buy the extension or use some Visual Studio subscriptions which included the extension. If you have created tests during the trial and the trial is over, TFS will show those test cases but you could not be able to create test cases any more.

Comment: yes ! i used Test Manager - it was best solution ! thanks you very much again !